# JSF outputstylesheet doesnt work in firefox?

Tags: java, css, firefox, jsf, jsf-2

I havea a problem with the outputStylesheet tag:

It works perfectly in chrome but doesnt work at all in firefox

```
    <h:head>
        <title><ui:insert name="title" /></title>
            <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />   
    </h:head>
```

What should i do to fix this problem? My application looks fine, but just in google chrome.

In FF the inspect element option shows the CSS file with all its options, but the browser does'nt display it at all.

Comment: 1) What exactly fails in FF? What's generated HTML output? What does Firebug say about response status and body for CSS? What does "Inspect element" tell about styles? 2) Curious, can you post full stacktrace? What JSF impl/version and server impl/version? I recall state saving issues related to this in older versions.

Comment: @BalusC 1) What fails in FF is that none of the CSS works as it does in Chrome or even IE 2)I fixed that issue, it looks like there was some unrelated error that was not allowing to build(outputstylesheet is now correctly placed in head tag). I use JSF 2.0, my web.xml says that it is version 3.0(Sorry i am not acurrate in this, i often get confused)

Comment: OK, then it's just a CSS issue. Is the CSS file loaded? (Firebug should give response status 200 with proper body content). Are you using 3rd party component libraries like PrimeFaces? It might just have overridden your style. What does "Inspect Element say about any overridden styles? Open page in Firefox, rightclick HTML element of interest, choose *Inspect Element*, on the right hand side of Firebug box you should see declared and overridden CSS properties. As to 2) it's not relavant anymore. With JSF impl/version I mean more like Mojarra 2.1.2 and Server impl/version like Glassfish 3.1.1.

Comment: @BalusC In this one i am not using any 3rd party libraries. But i did add a gadget called addThis(Social networking) `www.addthis.com` 

I did inspect elements and i see my CSS at the right, all looks as it is in the file. Just a few variables are striked over(like if they were uncompatible).



Ok i inspected some of the elements, and at the right i see the correct CSS that is on them

Comment: They will only be striked over if they are overridden by another CSS declaration. If the property was not supported, it would not have been appeared at all. Do you have multiple CSS files? It would be more helpful if you elaborate in detail what CSS properties were applied and what not. Saying "Doesn't work" gives us nothing to work with. You could show an SSCCE all the CSS and post some screens.

Comment: @BalusC no just one called style.css but maybe the gadget i added from addThis.com also is connected with some other style.css from somewhere else that is causing that problem?

Comment: That should be visible in the Firebug style inspector. Look what property is been strikeout and look further down for the same property and look where it's been declared. Make it less specific or add `!important` the property in your `style.css`. It's hard to give a specific answer based on the information given as far.

Comment: @BalusC Yes that was it! I renamed my style to myappstyle.css, and now it works also in FF as it does in Chrome. I should never again call my .css files just syle.css The problem is solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can happen when one or more CSS properties are been overridden by another stylesheet. Using Firebug should help you in nailing down the culprit. Open the page in Firefox, rightclick the HTML DOM element of interest and choose *Inspect Element*. Firebug should show up in the bottom box with the HTML DOM tree on the left hand side and a list of all CSS properties on the right hand side. If a property is been strikeout, then it means that there's another CSS property which has overridden it. In the same list, you should be able to find the responsible property and its location.